# Excel filter data and populate rows with result

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets, "Weekly" and "Daily".
The daily sheet should auto populate the names of people working for that day, based on the weekly sheet.
Names with empty cells should not be filled.
At the moment I am doing multiple nested-if statements, which is not the right solution. How do I use the index, small, row functions to populate it more dynamically? Sheet references:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

In **Daily!B3**:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX(Weekly!$B$1:$B$50,
SMALL(ISNUMBER(1/INDEX(Weekly!$D$5:$L$50,0,MATCH($A$1,Weekly!$D$2:$L$2,0)))*ROW($B$5:$B$50),
SUM(--(INDEX(Weekly!$D$5:$L$50,0,MATCH($A$1,Weekly!$D$2:$L$2,0))=0))+COLUMNS($A:A))),
"")
```

Notes:

- This is an array formula entered by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`
- The Dates and Weekday names are all "real" dates formatted to appear as specified.
- Although not recommended, the merged cells are merged as you showed.  Note that with merged cells, the only cell populated is that in the upper left corner of the merged area.
- Note that the "Names" column (Weekly!$B$1:$B$50) is referenced starting at Row 1; other regions start at Row 5 which is where your data starts.  All columns end at the same row.  If your table has more rows, adjust as needed.  It is OK to have more rows specified than exist in your data.
- I assumed five days, so ended at column L.  Adjust this as required.
- After entering the formula in B3 of the Daily sheet, fill right as far as required.
- Note that the second and third `INDEX` functions in the formula use **`0`** for the column argument.  This will return an array of the entire column.
- I will leave it to you to figure out how to populate the times.

### Weekly Table

[image: Weekly Table]

### Daily Table

[image: Daily Table]

Comment: What are the match functions for? More specifically, MATCH($A$1,Weekly!$D$2:$L$2,0). Also it seems that your cell references are in the format of $A$1 instead of A1. Is there a difference?

Comment: @user1999806 `MATCH`: note that `lookup_value` refers to the Date of the Daily sheet; and `lookup_array`refers to the range of dates on the weekly sheet.  So `MATCH` will return the column number (relative to column D) which contains the date on the weekly sheet corresponding to the date of the daily sheet.

Comment: @user1999806 `$A$1`  For information as to what this means, and other important information, read Excel Help re: **Overview of Formulas in Excel** and also  **Using references in Excel formulas**,